# How to use MultipartFormDataContent with Azure.Core RequestContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autorest

I'm trying to use an Autorest generated C# client to send `MultipartFormDataContent` but the request always fails as it seems that the `RequestContent` in `Azure.Core` does not seem to support naïve usage.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```cs
RequestContext myRequestContext = new RequestContext();
MultipartFormDataContent formData = myObject.ToMultipartFormDataContent();
RequestContent content = RequestContent.Create(formData);
myAutorestClient.MyEndpointPost(content, myRequestContext);
```

However, it seems as if the `RequestContent.Create` call fails to properly convert the `MultipartFormDataContent`.

Is there any guidance on how to properly send Multipart form data using the `Azure.Core` `RequestContent` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ConvertMultipartFormDataContent method to implement it.

```
private async Task<RequestContent> ConvertMultipartFormDataContent(MultipartFormDataContent formDataContent)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await formDataContent.CopyToAsync(ms);
        byte[] formDataAsBytes = ms.ToArray();
        return RequestContent.Create(formDataAsBytes);
    }
}
```

The usage should be like below:

```
public async Task<Response> Test(MyObject myObject, RequestContext myRequestContext)
{
    RequestContext myRequestContext = new RequestContext();
    MultipartFormDataContent formData = myObject.ToMultipartFormDataContent();
    RequestContent content = await ConvertMultipartFormDataContent(formData);
    return await myAutorestClient.MyEndpointPost(content, myRequestContext);
}
```